# How to know if a string belongs to a combination of lists of string in python?

Tags: python, list

I have complex lists of lists of lists… of unique string as the Following :

```
L = [['A'],[['B','C'],['D'],[['E'],['F','G']]]]
```

I would like to know if a particular string belongs to L.

Let's take a simple example :

```
L = [['A'],[['B'],['C']]]
```

I would like to know if 'B' is in L (so not the list ['B'] but the string 'B'). How could I do ?

Thanks

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: So,what was your output for above example? Is it bool value or something else?

Comment: Thanks for asking, it would be a boolean value indeed (Here, I would like to get True)

Comment: I tried things like any('B' in sublist for sublist in L) but it didn't work :/

Comment: Thanks for the post AkshayNevrekar :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, search will be easier if you flatten the original list.

```
import collections

def flatten(l):
    for el in l:
        if isinstance(el, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el, (str, bytes)):
            yield from flatten(el)
        else:
            yield el

flatten_L = list(flatten(L))

if 'B' in flatten_L:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this alternative solution !

Comment: Finally, your solution is the best for me as it doesn't take into account a string into a bigger string. For example, your solution with L = ['A',['BC','B']] will send False if I want to check 'C' and it is exactly what I want. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

Using Recursion.

```
def is_present(string_to_check, nested_list):
    output = False
    for element in nested_list:
         if isinstance(element, list):
             output = output or is_present(string_to_check, element)
         else:
             output = output or string_to_check in element
    return output
```

Answer (score 1):

Shorter recursive solution:

```
def exists(d, t):
  return any(i == t if not isinstance(i,list) else exists(i, t) for i in d)


L = [['A'],[['B'],['C']]]
print(exists(L, 'B'))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution !

Answer (score 0):

While the recursive solution produces the correct result, it continues to loop unnecessarily through the rest of the list elements after a match is found. This is an optimized version, which I believe is also clearer:

```
def is_present(string_to_check, nested_list):
    for element in nested_list:
        if isinstance(element, list):
            if is_present(string_to_check, element):
                return True
        elif string_to_check in element:
            return True
    return False


L = [['A'],[['B','C'],['D'],[['E'],['F','G']]]]
print(is_present('B', L))
```

Prints:

```
True
```